# Why NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs has NewItems and OldItems as plural?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm new to C# and OOP, just a question on `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`. I don't understand why it has NewItems and OldItems rather than `NewItem` and `OldItem`.
For example, we use ObservableCollection as:

```
ObservableCollection<Person> people = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
// Wire up the CollectionChanged event.
people.CollectionChanged += people_CollectionChanged;

static void people_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
   {
     foreach (Person p in e.NewItems)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
     }
   }

}
```

so each time we add a new `Person` in the collection as:

```
people.Add(new Person("John", "Smith", 32));
```

`CollectionChanged` trigger `people_CollectionChanged`, so `e.NewItems` will only contain one person (the one I just added), so what's the point to assume `e.NewItems` could have more than one item as it always can only have one item?

Comment: Hi, is there anything you're still unsure about with this question?

Answer (score 3):

The event you're subscribing to is actually defined by the [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface, and implemented by [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8).

While `ObservableCollection` doesn't have methods for adding multiple items at once, it does have a [`ClearItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.clearitems?view=netframework-4.8) method, which could remove multiple items at once. That's one reason I can think of for having plural names, since they could contain more than one item.

Also, since it's an interface, it could be implemented by other classes that do implement something like `AddRange` or `RemoveWhere`, etc. methods, which would again raise this event with multiple items.

Comment: Just checked, ClearItems actually raises the `Reset` action. From the source code, there is no action in ObservableCollection that raises an even with collection of items. In fact ObservableCollection doesnt even support bulk updates natively. I think those are there only for other types like BulkObservableCollection etc

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs.newitems?view=netframework-4.8), you will notice that the backing entity is an `IList` implementation. Given that it's a list, it's only natural that the property name is in plural.

For example, if I use [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange), multiple items will be added at once, and `NewItems` (or `OldItems`, if you removed content) would be populated with more than one entry.

Comment: I think OP's question more stems from a question as to why `ObservableCollection` returns a list in this event at all, rather than a single item. I don't think it's why the list name is plural, but why it's a list at all.

Comment: Sure, and the second line in my answer explains the underlying reasoning too :)